# Running Client application on server

Tags: java, client-server, httpclient, client-side

I have a server program running on the server TOMCAT 6.0.The server program is going to print the message "hello world" continueoulsy.Now I want to develop a client program,which when i start should go and run on the server and get that message displayed on the client.The restriction is that client should be invoked through commandline.The server program is written is java.I am new to this field,dont know what to do!help please!

Comment: I think you're confused with the architecture. Is this homework? I think what you want is a command-line client that makes a HTTP request to a URL, and displays the response from the server. If you google for *Java HTTP request*, you should get results.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use URLConnection class some like this.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
     public static void main(String[] args) 
         throws Exception {
          URL myURL = new URL("[Your servlet URL]");
          URLConnection yc =
          myURL.openConnection();
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                    yc.getInputStream()));
          String inputLine;

          while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
               System.out.println(inputLine);
          in.close();
     }
}
```

and in servlet, you have to write `response.getOutputStrem().println("Hello world");`